# Running SonarLint VisualStudio plugin without SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I have installed SonarLint extension (V 2.8) for Visual Studio 2015.
Can the code be analysed locally WITHOUT connecting to a SonarQube server?

Do I need to install something else in order to analyze my code (if i dont have SonarQube)?

I dont see the rulesets added to my project. How do I add rulesets? and from where?

I checked the SonarLint GitHub page but couldn't find the relevant documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you install SonarLint for Visual Studio, analysis results (warnings) will automatically show up in the Error Window. You might need to enable `Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Advanced/Enable full solution analysis` otherwise only open files will be analyzed.

Most of the rules are enabled by default, some of them are not. You can control this through the ruleset file, but when no ruleset file is present, the default rule activation is used. Rule enablement can be changed for each of your projects by right clicking on `References/Analyzers/Open Active Rule Set`. This part is documented on the SonarLint website here: [FAQ](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/faq.html#disable_rule). (Note that this is not specific to SonarLint though, it's the normal Visual Studio experience.)

Comment: The FAQ link is broken

Comment: As suggested Edit queue is full, keeping the answer reference link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019